# Property 'getData' does not exist on type 'ComponentClass'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I want to mock the axios call with jest ,but I get an error with only getData when using this testcase:

```
jest.mock('axios')
const mockAxios = axios as AxiosMock

it('make api call to get data', () => {
   // call this first
   mockAxios.mockResolvedValue(data)

   TestPublications.getData()
   expect(mockAxios.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith("http://app30.knipsel.lan:665/v1/publications/crud")
});
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproduce code. Otherwise, the question will be closed cause lack of detail.

Answer (score 0):

I take it that your TestPublications is your React class, if so the functions you write inside that are not methods in the normal Object-Oriented sense, you need to put `getData` outside the class in your file (eg. TestPublications.js) then export that function to test